# Look for consecutive numbers in a list

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to write this in Java, but I'm unsure of how to approach this could someone help guide me through this.

So at first I am getting users input from a range of 1 to 9 and it is stored in a list. After that I want to see if any of the numbers stored in the list are in sequential order without sorting.

Say I have these lists and it should return true or false because I am only looking at 4 places.

I don't want the list to be sorted because I still want to retain the original list.

Also they can have repeats which is something I'm also unsure about handling. Below is my pseudo code, but just not sure how to handle repeats because even if there is a repeat of a number I'd still want it to return true.

```
[1,2,3,4,6,9] true because the first four digits are consecutive
            
I want to be able to grab 4 from the list like the first 4 and see
if they are consecutive or not.

[1,2,4,5,6,7,8] true because the last 4 digits are consecutive
For this one it grabs the first 4, [1,2,4,5] checks to see if they are  

consecutive or not then it moves onto the 

next 4: [2,4,5,6] which is false so it goes 

onto the next 4: [4,5,6,7] which is true.

[3,2,4,5,6,7,9,1,8] true because 4,5,6,7, are consecutive
Iterates through the first four then next four until            
there is a sequential order otherwise it returns false.

[5,2,4,1,7] false because there is no consecutive
  

[1,2,3,5,6] false because there is no consecutive of at least 4.
[1,2,2,3,4] true as well.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Im still trying to get the first four elements in the array to see if they are sequential if not then it moves along into the array and gets the next 4 to see if they're sequential or not and keeps on iterating until it finds that there is a sequence in the array and returns true or until when the array is finished and it cant find any sequential order and returns a false.

Comment: @JohnYang Makes complete sense, you are on the right track.

Comment: @JohnYang I don't agree with your accepted answer of choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the right track, your thought process with coming up with that pseudocode was extremely easy to follow, great job:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    assertTrue(fourConsecutive(new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9}));
    assertTrue(fourConsecutive(new int[] {1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}));
    assertTrue(fourConsecutive(new int[] {3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 1, 8}));
    assertFalse(fourConsecutive(new int[] {5, 2, 4, 1, 7}));
    assertFalse(fourConsecutive(new int[] {1, 2, 3, 5, 6}));

    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
      int arrayLength =
          getIntegerInput(scanner, "How many numbers are you going to enter: ", 0, 10);
      int[] array = new int[arrayLength];
      for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        array[i] = getIntegerInput(scanner, String.format("Enter number %d: ", i + 1), 1, 9);
      }
      System.out.println(
          fourConsecutive(array)
              ? "There is a sequence of four consecutive numbers in the numbers you entered: "
                  + Arrays.toString(array)
              : "There is a not a sequence of four consecutive numbers in the numbers you entered: "
                  + Arrays.toString(array));
    }
  }

  private static boolean fourConsecutive(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 3; i++) {
      if (arr[i + 1] == arr[i] + 1 && arr[i + 2] == arr[i] + 2 && arr[i + 3] == arr[i] + 3) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  private static int getIntegerInput(Scanner scanner, String prompt, int minValue, int maxValue) {
    System.out.print(prompt);
    int validInteger = -1;
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
      if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        validInteger = scanner.nextInt();
        if (validInteger >= minValue && validInteger <= maxValue) {
          break;
        } else {
          System.out.printf(
              "Error: Please enter an integer between %d and %d inclusive%n", minValue, maxValue);
          System.out.print(prompt);
        }
      } else {
        System.out.printf(
            "Error: Please enter an integer between %d and %d inclusive%n", minValue, maxValue);
        System.out.print(prompt);
        scanner.next();
      }
    }
    return validInteger;
  }
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
How many numbers are you going to enter: 14
Error: Please enter an integer between 0 and 10 inclusive
How many numbers are you going to enter: 8
Enter number 1: 12
Error: Please enter an integer between 1 and 9 inclusive
Enter number 1: 3
Enter number 2: 8
Enter number 3: 4
Enter number 4: 5
Enter number 5: 6
Enter number 6: 7
Enter number 7: 1
Enter number 8: 9
There is a sequence of four consecutive numbers in the numbers you entered: [3, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this method works:

```
public boolean find4Consecutive(int[] array) {
    int length = array.length;
    for(int i = 0; i+4<=length; i++ ) {
        int current = array[i];
        int current1 = array[i+1];
        int current2 = array[i+2];
        int current3 = array[i+3];
        if(current+1==current1&&current1+1==current2&&current2+1==current3) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**What are we doing?**

We are looping through the array and checking whether the 3 items in the array after the current index are equal to the previous item plus 1.

**Test Run**

`[1,2,3,4,6,9]` returns `true`

`[0, 2, 3, 4, 5]` returns `true`

`[0, 2, 4, 4, 5]` returns `false`